# MOSFET differential amplifier

Tags: mosfet, nmos, differential-amplifier

[image]

I have two questions about this circuit.

As operating points, Vds=(Vdd-Ir*Rd)-(-Vgs). I do not understand why we put -Vgs.

The second question is, if we take only one output (Vo1) what would Acm (common mode gain) be?

Answer (score 0):

> I do not understand why we put -Vgs.

For the operating point, \$V_{M2,DS} = V_{M2,drain} - V_{M2,source}\$

We can see from our schematic that \$V_{M2,drain} = V_{o2} = V_{DD} - I_R\cdot R_D\$, while \$V_{M2,source} = V_2 - V_{M2,GS}\$

For some reason, the \$V_2\$ is assumed zero, for which I can only conclude that this is where the operating point is calculated. So you would get \$V_{M2,DS} = (V_{DD} - I_R\cdot R_D) - (V_2 - V_{M2,GS})\$ with \$V_2=0\$.

> The second question is, if we take only one output (Vo1) what would Acm(vommon mode gain) be?

To calculate the common mode gain, you will apply a common mode voltage, i.e. you make sure that \$V_1 = V_2\$, and calculate the gain from \$V_1\$ or \$V_2\$ to one of the outputs.

You can split the current source in two equal parts and split the problem up to get this circuit:

[image: Differential amplifier split]

Due to symmetry, there is no current through the dotted wire, so you can simply remove it for the common mode gain calculation. You only have to solve either the left or the right half and the result will be identical. The common mode gain will then simply be \$V_{o1}/V_1\$ or \$V_{o2}/V_2\$.